# CSS or JS - Keep image outside on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achive is similar to the slideshow on this template http://www.agence-me.com/html/k/

Notice how the image in the slide is cut when you resize the window. Could this be achived with pure CSS or JS?

I know that I can resize an image with the screen using

```
.img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
<img src="..." class="img" />
```

But I want to keep the image fixed to the max browser size and not change it's dimensions with resizing the window.

Comment: how do you define the max browser size? the size of their browser when they open your page? the size of the users screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this css only DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/tCxw3/1/

You want like this? Resize and see the effect, the image size is 1600x1200 px.

```
div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YUUHSmN2iKc/URqH5KMr6OI/AAAAAAAABpE/ta3lwt2KDx8/s400/desktop-wallpaper-1600x1200.jpg) no-repeat center left fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

max-width: 500px; limits it to a maximum of 500px so it won't get larger.

Hope this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the image a background image in a div, and using CSS background position, like this:

```
.img{
    background-position:50% 50%; 
}
```

This would make it continually stay centered, exactly like the example.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing some clever resizes on the `window.onresize` event to give the appearance of zooming/stretching the image to fill the given space.  The image itself is `1600x998`, so there is not much worry of degradation of quality.